# Comparing Factorie and Figaro languages for Statistical Relational Learning

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network, probabilistic-programming

I am looking to implement statistical relational learning, preferably in a modern programming language, and came across [Factorie](http://factorie.cs.umass.edu/) and [Figaro](https://www.cra.com/commercial-solutions/probabilistic-modeling-services.asp) for Scala. But most resources online that compare these are a little outdated, since these are under active development.

> How does Factorie compare against Figaro now? (and how do these compare
>   against the C++ based [Alchemy](https://code.google.com/p/alchemy-2/)?)

Some features that I would like to seem compared on are:

- Directed (Bayesian Logic) and Undirected (Markov Logic) graphical models
- Inductive and deductive inference algorithms for first order logic
- Learning algorithms
- Support for Dynamic, time-series algorithms (for first order logical inference)
- Support for higher order (probabilistic) logic